# Ionic React / Capacitor, requests work on web version and with postman but not on a device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, axios

I'm using axios to make requests to fetch the data from my external API (it's HTTP AWS server with ExpressJS and Nginx). I tested it on my local machine with the web version of my Ionic app and everything is working expected. Also I can fetch data if I'm using my phone's browser.

Same goes with postman, I can fetch data without any problems.

The only place where these requests don't work is the actual device. Looking at the Android Studio console the error is: "Msg: Network Error" (failing to figure out how to get more from axios error object).

I configured CORS following the official Ionic documentation. I've set all needed origins and options (can't use * origin because I have to use credentials with my requests). Express configuration looks like this:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: [
    'http://localhost:8100',
    'http://localhost:8080',
    'http://localhost',
    'capacitor://localhost',
    'ionic://localhost',
  ],
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"]
}

// Enable preflight requests for all routes
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));


app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

On the client (request example):

```
try {
  const response = await axios('http://my.api.url', {
    method: 'get',
    withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    });
  
  const data = response.data;
      
  // Do something with the data
      
} catch(error) {
  console.log(error);       
};
```

I think it has something to do with Capacitor, maybe there is a problem with non-https API (but then the question is why does it work with the web version). I tried disabling credentials for my requests but the error reoccur. Also removing Nginx doesn't seem to change anything.

Update: Also the axios says the request is sent but the server didn't respond.

Comment: Hi. 3 years later byt I am writting a capacitor (reactjs) app for mobile and I am having problems with requests. First of all, does axios work ok with mobile? Secondly, I am using capacitor's official http plugin (ex comminuty) and cannot figure out how to add request timeout and baseURL. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't remember all the details, but axios definitely worked on Android. I mean it had to be over https with cors properly set up.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @serjuice. Do you know anything regarding iOS and axios? Also, how can I find info how to setup the axios CORS properly to work on mobile devices? Thank you :)

Comment: I think it should work on iOS too, just make sure your web server is set up correctly, because that was the problem with my configuration. Also, I'm not sure, but I think you should add internet permission to android manifest file in order to actually use internet in your app. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I will start searching those things you mentioned.i hope I can make it work. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sorted it out, I had to do following.

1. Had to add a SSL to my web server (I used letsencrypt).
2. Had to add this to capacitor.config.json:

   "server": {
   "allowNavigation": [
   "my.api.url"
   ]
   }

[Official Capacitor Documentation - Common Configuration](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/basics/configuring-your-app#common-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the CSRF Token Issue with Laravel.

Simply go to,

`app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

And In there add `'api/*'` inside the protected $except array like this, (This is a quick solution)

```
protected $except = [
    'api/*'
  ];
```