Setup API connection for Reactjs + Laravel API + Capacitor in Android device
There's a problem for API connection. Here I want to make a POST request, but connection failed/network error.
The code:

Home.jsx

try {
      // const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/submitqrcode', { qr_code_data: data },
      //   getConfig()
      // );
      const response = await CapacitorHttp.post({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/submitqrcode',
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        data: {qr_code_data: data},
      })


capacitor.config.json

{
  "appId": "com.example.app",
  "appName": "QR Code Reader",
  "webDir": "build",
  "plugins": {
    "CapacitorHttp": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}

What I've tried:

using Axios


Error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED


https://stackoverflow.com/a/63521379/19540100
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63334324/19540100
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70146875/19540100


using CapacitorHttp


Error: "ConnectException" message: "Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:8000"

Although I've tried 2 different methods, but both are showing the same type of error, which is can't connect to API. Why and how to solve this?

since both your mobile app and laravel installation are not on the same machine, they can't reach each other with 127.0.01 since that target "local machine". Use local network IP address but first you need to open the port for local network.

@N69S how to do that?

use something like xamp to host your application and open the port. if its the only app on your localhost, you can reach it with the local network ip address. if you have multiple applications, use vhosts and you will need to edit the host file on your android (you need root for that) and add those vhosts to point to the desired ip. In all case, google it. there might be other solution I didnt think of of the top of my head. "how to reach my head. for example this https://locall.host/localhost-android/

@N69S thanks for the method! btw what's the keywords for googling this method u mentioned?

Ok I have found an insight from people in discord which resulted as a solution in my case.
So you will need a web server to host your backend. Thanks to my boss's help, here are the steps:

Setup your DB connection and laravel env file with the web server's credentials
Use the web server's url at the axios request in your frontend
Install filezilla (or any that suits you) to save updated files to the server

Tadaa & you're done!
So in conclusion, you will need a web server to host your backend in android devices.
